# Natural density of the intersection of a set and it's translate

Tags: number-theory

Suppose $A\subset \mathbb{N}$ is such that it's natural (asymptotic) density exists. Recall that the natural density is defined as
$$
\delta(A) := \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\left|\left\{n\leq N\ |\ n\in A\right\}\right|.
$$

From the definition, it follows that $\delta(A) = \delta(A+h)$ for any fixed $h\in \mathbb{N}$. Here $A+h$ is the translate of $A$ defined by

$$
A+h = \{n+h\ |\ n\in A\}.
$$

My question is regarding whether $\delta(A \cap (A+h))$ exists or not. Equivalently we may ask whether $\delta(A\cup (A+h))$ exists.

It is well known that the intersection of two sets with natural densities need not have a natural density and there are well documented counter examples. However, I am not able to find any reference to the above question. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Say that $x \in A$ if $x \pmod 2 = 0$ and $\lceil \log_2 x\rceil$ is odd, or $x \pmod 4 \in \{0, 1\}$ and $\lceil \log_2 x\rceil$ is even: first members are $1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 17, 20, 21, 24, 25, 28, 29, 32, 34, \ldots, 62, 64, 65, 68, 69, \ldots$ - take every second element for numbers that have even length in binary, and take every second pair for numbers that have odd length.

Then density of $A$ is $1/2$ (number of elements less than $n$ doesn't deviate from $n / 2$ by more than a constant), but $B = A \cap (A + 1) = \{x | x \pmod 4 = 1 \wedge \lceil \log_2 x \rceil \text{is even}\}$ doesn't have natural density.

Indeed, if $n > 0$ then $|B \cap [2^{2n}, 2^{2n + 2})| = 2^{2n - 2} = \frac{1}{12} \cdot |[2^{2n}, 2^{2n + 2})|$, but $|B \cap [2^{2n + 1}, 2^{2n + 3})| = 2^{2n} = \frac{1}{6} \cdot |[2^{2n + 1}, 2^{2n + 3})|$.
So, density on $[1, 2^{2n+2})$ is combination of densities on $[1, 2^{2})$, $[2^2, 2^4)$, $\ldots$, which are all except the first $1/12$ - so density on $[1, 2^{2n + 2})$ is approximately $1/12$.
Similarly, density on $[1, 2^{2n + 1})$ is combination of densities on $[1, 2^1)$, $[2^1, 2^3)$, $\ldots$, which are all except the first one $1/6$, so density on $[1, 2^{2n + 1})$ is approximately $1/6$. Thus $B$ doesn't have natural density.

Using longer segments, we can get arbitrary densities less than $1/2$.